# how I can prove this summation?

Tags: complex-numbers, summation

prove that
$$\left| \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k z_k \right|^2 =
\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left| a_k \right|^2 \right)\;\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left| z_k \right|^2 \right)-\sum_{1\leq j< k\leq n}\left| a_j\overline{z_k}-a_k\overline{z_j} \right|^2$$

where $a_k,z_k $ are complex numbers

Comment: This is known as Lagrange's identity for complex numbers and it is proven here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_identity

Answer (score 0):

You need to use properties of $\overline{\cdot}$.

- $x\overline{x}=|x|^2$
- $\overline{\overline{x}}=x$
- $\overline{x+y}=\overline{x}+\overline{y}$ so by recurrence $\overline{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n x_k}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \overline{x_k}$
- $\overline{xy}=\overline{x}\overline{y}$ so by recurrence $\overline{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n x_k}=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \overline{x_k}$

Use the first property to remove all the $|\cdot|$, then move the $\overline{\cdot}$ to single variables instead of having them on sums or products and simplify all the $\overline{\overline{x}}$ using the other properties. Then distribute the products so that you have sums of products on both sides. Then remove the terms that appear on both sides and after doing that you should get $0=0$. Since all the steps you used are reversible and $0=0$ is true, your equality is proved.

Comment: Are you sure? The LHS is symmetric in $a_k$ and $z_k$, but on the RHS there are no $\bar a_k$.

Comment: If you use the first property, you'll get some.